# Add "Show All" option in dropdown filter of datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables

I implemented dropdown filter using datatables.

### HTML File

```
<select id='filter'>
    <option value>Show All</option>
    <option value='1'>one</option>
    ...
    <option value='10'>ten</option>
</select>

<table id='table'>
    ...
</table>
```

### Javascript

```
var table = $("#table").DataTable();

$("#filter").change(function(){
    var filterValue = $(this).selectedOptions[0].label;

    if ( filterValue == '' ){
        // **Show All Functionality**

    } else {
        table.column(2).search(filterValue).draw();
    }
});
```

If I select one to ten, it works fine, but I want to show all again after filter was applied.
Is there any function to do so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to draw the table again, after searching for an empty string (which should return all rows):
`table.search('').draw();`

And if that works, you can get rid of the `if` clause and just do:

```
$("#filter").change(function() {
    table.search($(this).val()).draw();
});
```

Comment: I changed javascript a little, check that and please help me again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to make small changes in your code as follows:

```
<option value='0'>Show All</option>  // Set value as 0 for "Show All" option   

 var table = $("#table").DataTable();

 $("#filter").change(function(){
       var filterValue = $(this).val();

       if ( filterValue == '0' ){  // Check for show all option
            table.search(filterValue).draw(); 

       } else {
            table.search(filterValue).draw();
       }
    });
```

Comment: I changed javascript a little, check that and please help me again, thanks.